# What is a help vampire?

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

I've seen several posts about help vampires, but I don't really understand what is meant by that phrase. What exactly is a help vampire?

Comment: See : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/help-vampire/synonyms

Comment: [The Help Vampire problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem).

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20181124221026/http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm

Comment: lmgtfy/help-vampire  "Does he clearly lack the ability or inclination to ask the almighty Google?"

Comment: @Will: Oh you did *not* just do that... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions

Comment: Is this supposed to be some clever demonstration of Help Vampirism?

Comment: Another feature of a help vampire is a help vampire of course lacks the ability to look at themselves in the mirror to see that they are engaging in problematic behavior.

Comment: Open up Google and type help-vampire. Wait 0.14 seconds and ...... *start regretting*...

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be a Help Vampire himself, unlike what some commenters are saying: he has apparently posted about ten times as many answers as questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I actually searched Help Vampire on Meta to see if there was a discussion about it and seeing none, I decided to ask the question. I assumed that it was a Stack Exchange exclusive term since I'd never heard it before.

Comment: [Oh the irony](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=help+vampire)

Comment: Hover over the tag 'help-vampire'

Comment: As an illustration of how bad search engine results are nowadays, the ***original [slash7.com blog post](https://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)***, that coined the term in 2006, two years before Stack Overflow were twinkles in Atwood's and Spolsky's eyes, did not show up on the first page searching for "`help vampire`"... (Though this very page was #1!)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

According to [the Help Vampire tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/help-vampire):

> The Help Vampire problem is the idea that some users will continually ask the same tired questions in the hope that someone else will do their work for them, irrespective of whether the same question has already been asked or whether they could easily find the solution elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, the irony! `:P`

Comment: Proof of just how silly and self centered this 'community' is.

Comment: @Carl, When someone asks 15 to 20 questions over 4 days, all of which were easily answerable if they just read some docs or tutorials on the topic question they're being a help vampire. We aren't here to be your personal tutors or manual references.

Answer (score 101):

Here are some further symptoms of a help vampire, viz a poster who treats the SO community as they would an online product support chat helpline, i.e. a user who:

- Will continue to extend the original question with continued questions, even after the original question has been well answered.
- Provides just a brief and vague overview about the problem, omitting vital information, and assumes that answerers are able to grok the context of the poster's problem, as if he/she were asking his/her team lead the problem directly.
- Will attempt to pester an answerer with continued questions several days later, on unrelated matters.
- And once they've sucked every last ounce of life from you, will then disappear without so much as a thanks, upvote or answer tick.

[And](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058300) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30506922/314291) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650523/314291) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23307298/314291) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606517/sql-update-from-other-tables)

[?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162146/a-web-programming-mentor)

Comment: I like the "doesn't work" problem.

Comment: extending and continuing the already answered question is also known as ["chameleon"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: "it doesn't work" is the mantra of the help vampire.

Comment: I have recently had the first REAL help vamipire experence, these day, It fits perfectly your description, so I would give you the 10x upvote, if I could. I'm wondering if in this case it is better to delete my own answer.

Comment: Your second item is simply poor question authoring skills or laziness. Some help vampires are lazy, others aren't.

Comment: Yeah, don't we all love it when the "one more question in comments" ping pong game starts.

Answer (score 92):

I like the [JavaScript Chatroom Rules](http://rlemon.github.io/so-chat-javascript-rules/#asking) definition:

> 1. Do you get more code from Stack Overflow than you write on your own?
> 2. Do you feel entitled to help from Stack Overflow users?
> 3. Do you believe in the philosophy "Just use jQuery"?
> 4. Do you spend more time looking for the right "plugin" than you likely would writing it on your own?
>
> If you answered "Yes" to any of these questions, there is a good chance you are a Help Vampire. Sorry.

Comment: number 3 is dumb. i love jquery.

Comment: @r3wt I love children, but I wouldn't ask them to wash my house

Comment: @Martin lol, say what?

Comment: @r3wt jQuery has its uses, but just because you love it, does not mean it is the answer to every problem.

Comment: @jQuery no one says it was. I always use jQuery (with vanilla js where appropriate). it alleviates alot of the tediousness of javascript for a vast majority of things a web developer needs to do in regards to working with the dom.

Comment: I know nothing about code, so I'm having a hard time understanding how those examples are relevant. :(

Comment: @PrittBalagopal #3 is a joke. I'm not sure what's wrong with #4 either.

Comment: Not sure I agree with #4, if there's plugin already written for what you want to do then you shouldn't waste time writing your own. #2 is a fantastic point

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you failed to notice the keywords in the sentence, let me emphasize them for you : **spend more time looking**. Of course plugins are good, but when you **spend more time looking** for plugins than it would take you to write the whole plugin yourself, there's something wrong. At this point, chances are very high you'll end up asking a question about which tool/tutorial/plugin to use on StackOverflow, get downvoted, and wonder why.

Comment: @2Dee, the problem is that developers rarely measure the time spent debugging code and enabling it to scale. A good developer can write a new programming language in a week. Does that mean that any team that spends more than 1 week exploring various programming languages should just write their own?

Comment: @r3wt Then you are not a "just use jQuery" guy. One thing is to alleviate tedious DOM processes, and other thing is using jQuery even to iterate through a native array (nothing about DOM elements here). When I saw that iteration I was like "wtf..."

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález you probably have a valid point. I don't really have the time to get back in the mode of this, i'm too busy working on react and react-native now. ironic, perhaps, i was campaigning hard for jquery. biased

Comment: Items 1 and 2 are valid, items 3 and 4 are really more about style-of-coding. Someone could answer both of those "Yes" while never having asked a question on SO at all.

Answer (score -1):

To me, help vampire is somebody who

- seemingly asks a question
- in the truth, he wants to let others to do his task.

If they would ask their real problem:

> I am tired and won't work. Here is this code, make it ready for me.

Then this question would be closed. So, they mask it with a question:

> This tool works, but X and Y are bad in it. How could I fix it?

*Tasks* masked as *questions* are evil. They suck out the blood of the capable programmers. And without blood, their brain won't work any more, to produce useful code.

In my opinion, these people should get answers at most as if they had asked really questions. We shouldn't ever do the task of other, instead him.

Answer (score -7):

Let me restate and qualify @CarlOnager's [deleted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258325) in a hopefully less inflammatory way:

"Help vampirism" is an impression we may have about someone's behavior. It is likely to be at least in part a projection of our own frustration at having given much of ourselves in helping others - perhaps even too much in helping some individual person - only to be faced with another question in a similar vein from the same user.

So, it is perhaps not useful to try to categorize *people* as "help vampires"; and to be careful even when defining people's behavior with this pejorative. And be seven times more careful when you apply some sanction due to a user being a supposed "help vampire".

Comment: No. For me it's more akin to (providing an answer)"when I do this, I get am error"... (after prodding)"the error is X" ... (after addressing it)"okay, now I get this error"... (addressing that too) "this isn't working"... If you feel drained reading this, the vampire has fed on you too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: What if it's a reputation-1 user, and, say, a teenager who doesn't understand what they're doing?

Comment: I'd say you are doing a disservice to teenagers and newcomers combined. Asking for help in a non-draining manner is not a skill reserved to the yogis. I tutored enough teenagers to know.

Comment: I'm on board that we shouldn't label *people* – but I don't see what's wrong about labelling behaviour with a *term describing behaviour*. I especially why don't see how this answer motivates that one should not sanction a frustrating behaviour. Can you elaborate these parts, please?