# What to do when a user doesn't understand even the basic of his code?

Tags: support

So I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144951/javafx-how-to-get-selected-row-data-in-table-view-with-checkbox) where the user had a bad/hard to understand grammar (I edited it).

And what he asked was to change the output on his console, while it was clear that the output should be as expected considering how "(*his?*)" code was written.

When I saw his rep, I thought it was a new user (5) so I answered his question and fixed what was an actual problem in his code, and then told him how to change it into what he expected.

But then, when I saw his profile it appears that I found a mix of a [help-vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) and [Lacks minimal understanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back).

At the same time that I appreciate that got my +15 rep for such question, I feel bad because it doesn't feel right to help under such circumstances.

I didn't do anything, but I don't really know what I should do in this case.

**What would be the proper way to handle this situation?**

Comment: I am not very good with titles, feel free to edit it to a better one.

Comment: Describe how one would go about creating a solution, rather than providing the complete code of a solution.  Anyone interested in/capable of learning will be able to create a solution given the approach.

Comment: Well, don't help the user, help the next 100 programmers that google the question.  Does that make you feel better?  Don't respond to "one more problem" comments.

Comment: Agreed, just walk away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be argued that a good answer to a question is an answer that the asker will understand. An answer that teaches him to fish rather than gives him a fish. If the asker really has almost no understanding of the basics of their question, a good answer will be very long. It can be argued that the question should therefore be closed as being *too broad*.

Comment: In another context, a USENET newsgroup, I got frustrated with two classes of issues, not knowing how to start writing a program, and not knowing how to debug. I wrote a pair of "how to fish" web pages, and just posted links to them as appropriate. Unfortunately, that does not work for SO because it discourages link-only answers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The equivalent for SO is to close the question as  a duplicate of a canonical question that indicates these basics.