# Did I handle this situation correctly?

Tags: discussion

I've only recently started answering questions on SO and I recently came across this.

[Stream was not readable is caused when use readbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454252/stream-was-not-readable-is-caused-when-use-readbinary/24454589#24454589)

I felt that the question was evolving however, it was very easy to answer and I probably could have answered it there but I felt that answering it like that would change the focus of the answer in such a way so that the answer wasn't answering the question anymore. I told him to ask another question.

He did :
[Unable to read beyond the end of the stream is caused when use readbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455105/unable-to-read-beyond-the-end-of-the-stream-is-caused-when-use-readbinary/24455168#24455168)

I also answered this one. I feel guilty because I feel like I'm farming points. Did I do the correct thing? Is this what a vampire is?

Comment: Yes to both: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire#258279

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you did it right.