# Why am I unable to begin questions with "Hi"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, title

Why are users unable to begin questions with the phrase "Hi," ?

It appears that an introductory "Hi," is automatically deleted. Using the homonym "High," seems to work. But "Hi," is consistently deleted.

Comment: By Design [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/145673)

Comment: Salutations are considered "noise" and are typically edited out of posts. It's not to be rude but additional information such as "Hi, I'm new" and "thank you" which is irrelevant to the issue just take away from the problem at hand.

Comment: It is automatically removed because politely asking users not to do this did not work.

Comment: We're on the internet and we're impatient

Comment: People are less likely to answer posts starting with hi ?

Comment: Hi, we don't need to have anything extra, just the question only.  Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

From the tour page:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Scenario: You have a problem in your code that you cannot bend your head around and decide to search the Internet for an answer. After crafting what you believe is a well-designed search string, you end up with the following.

[image: Search Engine Results]

Wouldn't you really rather have this:

[image: Real search engine results]

Yes, those results are exaggerated but they are stretched to make a point. StackOverflow's purpose is not solely about the questioner. Its stated purpose is:

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

The people helped by the posted answers far outweigh the actual actual question posters. A good question can have anywhere from 100 to 100K (or more) views. If a question and its associated answers have helped at least a small portion of those 100K viewers, then SO has done its job.

Narrative debris is discouraged because it distracts from future viewers finding relevant material to answer their own questions. To that end, a well crafted question that gets to the point as quickly as possible helps as many people as the answers that accompany it.

<sub>I'm sure this will question be marked duplicate from somewhere but this is my take on the subject matter.</sub>

Comment: Why do you not care about Dave, Jeeped?

Comment: Love the freehand text

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Apparently, I am an SO [coding elitist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283163/removing-phrases-like-i-looked-everywhere-on-the-internet-and-i-did-not-find-an/283301#comment141348_283301) and coding elitists don't care about n00bs.