# Editing questions to add subsequent errors

Tags: discussion

I have experienced this scenario several times now where I provide an answer to a question which fixes the OP's issue but their code then goes on to throw a subsequent, different error. The OP neither accepts nor upvotes the answer but edits the question to give details of the additional error and comments on the answer to the effect that now they have another problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975601/symfony-2-unable-to-pass-entity-repository-to-form/30975785?noredirect=1#comment49984069_30975785) I recently answered is a classic case.

I generally get the impression the OP doesn't really appreciate the help given so far and has made little or no effort to find a solution to the new error themselves. They seem to be using SO as a free debugging service.

Is this an acceptable thing to do and if not is there an established practice for dealing with it? Comment that they should post a new question? Down-vote the existing question?

Edited to add: In this case I think the OP's edit reduces the usefulness of the Q&A to other users as the original error (which relates to the question title) has been struck out. I feel it would be better if the OP's edit (or at least the strikethrough) were reversed.

Comment: [Load up on Garlic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206).

Comment: @TZHX That's helpful, thank you, and led me to a possible duplicate of this question.

Comment: _edits the question to give details of the additional error_ Sounds like they just made their question too broad.

Comment: If OP adds extra error messages that change the underlying question, then he or the community should overhaul the question title and body. I did something similar [to my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30242006/revisions) when I found the underlying cause.

Comment: @onebree But only if it doesn't invalidate existing answers

Comment: @TinyGiant, yes. For my situation, no one had attempted to answer my question yet.