# How to handle a user asking multiple questions on same subject?

Tags: discussion, questions, users

I've encountered a user who keeps asking question on the same subject. It appears that he is doing a project and having lots of trouble along the way, asking questions each time he encounters one.

I feel is using the site as free workers to do his job, as there does not appear to be any time spent in trial and error or other research prior to asking.

What should I do in this case? Or should I just just ignore it?

Comment: downvote and move on (if it's low quality). however, don't just go through his profile downvoting, they'll just get reverted by the serial voting script. If he asks followup questions in comments, it's up to you to decide what to do. I help if the user isn't asking me to do their work for them, otherwise i don't. In this case i'd just ignore the comment and move on.

Comment: Seems a [help-vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) to me

Comment: Meh, they are [sql] questions.  Much like [regex], nobody ever researches anything, Google is rarely helpful and these questions get answered anyway.  Some experts get a *lot* of rep out them.  Just add [sql] to your ignored tags in your profile if you don't want to see them.

Comment: @KevinB Is not lile my rep get damage, but just wondering why I got so many downvote? this isn't the place to ask for help something like that? Or is the way I made the question?. And don't worry I wont be a serial down voter

Comment: No idea. voting on meta is weird.

Comment: related: [Fix serial downvoting reversal to not apply to users spamming site front page with bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199418/fix-serial-downvoting-reversal-to-not-apply-to-users-spamming-site-front-page-wi)

Comment: @KevinB Downvoting on Meta primarily expresses disagreement.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'd guess the downvotes might be from people who are seeing this as user shaming

Comment: @Patrice Thanks for your comment. Much better that just a downvote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That makes no sense whatever. It's a request for support! What is there to disagree with? *"Oh, you came to ask for help. I downvote!"*.

Comment: As Patrice stated, the original version of this question seemed designed to direct negative attention at a particular user. Folks on Meta tend to frown on public shaming of individuals, because that can turn into a vigilante mob pretty quickly. Shog9's edit made this a more generic question, and avoids calling out anyone in particular.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Patrice comment make sense. I did direct shame to an user. And now I see Shog9 update to my question I realize what I did wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza let's not get into the "downvote VS comment" debate here :P. But yeah, in general, first time I read your question it didn't look like a "what should I do to change this kinda behavior", but really like a "this guy is doing something wrong, let's grab the pitchforks and go burn him". You probably didn't mean that, but it's easy to interpret that and then downvote based off of this.

Comment: Alright, I only saw the latest revision, I didn't see the earlier ones. :/

Answer (score 4):

The community, including you, has all the tools available to handle this behavior.

First of all, if the question is unclear or lacks an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), down vote the queston and flag / close vote for the appropriate reason.

If questions are related/duplicate enough you could close vote as a duplicate of an earlier question.

Check if the question could use an edit or retag to make it cleared and to make sure it sees the correct audience.

It is not forbidden to extend a next question on a previous one so in theory there is not much wrong with that but all questions should conform to the quality guides for the site and the tags used.

Once you answered you might want to stay-away from further helping out to prevent falling victim to the [help-vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) problem.

Beyond that there is nothing more to do, unless you run to a chat room for help. But acting on a single user by a room is not something that will be appreciated so you can only go on a question by question basis.

I do notice that not many users seem to down vote or close vote those questions. That can be the agreed way of going forward by the sql-server sub-community but that leaves them with user profiles and questions you stumbled into. If it drains to much energy, just find another question or do as [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303518/multiple-questions-on-same-subject#comment238569_303518) suggested, ignore the tag.