# Are your questions less likely to be answered if you're a "leech"?

Tags: discussion

I was just wondering if there is some sort of penalty or if your questions probably won't be answered, if all you do is ask but never answer any questions on SO. Or just never contribute to anything in general.

I know the SO community might consider you a bit of a 'leech', but is there anything **else**, such as reputation loss, that might occur?

**EDIT**: I know that SO is not about getting insane amounts of rep, And it's a place to find answers. I just used rep lost as an example.

Comment: If you want a definitive answer you can use Stack Exchange Data Explorer to see if there's any such correlation.

Comment: (Though even if there is a correlation that might not imply causation as people that answer questions may well use that experience to ask better questions.)

Comment: The [statistics about that](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is publicly available, so you could go and analyze it. There might be a minor effect.

Comment: Honestly, if Stack Overflow has taught us anything, it's that Good Questions quickly become in much shorter supply than Good Answers.  Once you have a good question, you're more than halfway to having the problem solved.

Comment: As long as your question shows a real effort on your part, you are not a *leech* but a valuable contributor.

Comment: Well, _maybe kinda_? Posting more answers might make you more visible, and if more people see what you write, they might be more likely to click to your profile, where they might see/search in your questions and thus have more chance to answer them... but that, of course, would only be because of different visibility, not any deliberately choice not to answer. **and** crucially, the same thing might be said about good questions... or bad questions, or bad answers. ;-) so I'm not sure there's any direct correlation at all.

Comment: @underscore_d well you make an interesting point.

Comment: You say SO is a place to find answers, but the truth is it's just as much about cataloging questions. I can [speak from experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/35936/4424) that [questions can spark change](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/38518/4424).

Answer (score 137, accepted):

No.

People *could* go to your profile, click around a bit, see that you're only asking questions. They *could* then decide to not answer your question or downvote it. And while I can't see what people are doing on the site, I'm pretty sure that almost no one does this. Most people just look at the content of the question, and make their judgement based on that.

> just never contribute to anything in general. I know the SO community might consider you a bit of a 'leech'

Not at all. Asking *good* questions **is** contributing. People who answer questions on Stack Overflow *come here to answer questions*. Asking *good* questions is a vital component of that.

This doesn't mean Stack Overflow doesn't have its share of "leeches". The [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258206/660921) is the most notorious of them, but merely "asking questions" is *not* enough to be considered a leech. Just make sure your questions are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [can actually be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you should be fine (this may seem like an open door, but unfortunately it's not so obvious for everyone...)

Comment: Ok. I think i get ya.

Comment: And as far as reputation is concerned, good questions will get upvoted.

Comment: Say what you want, but I **do** do this. If someone only asks questions, or their QA ratio is 9 or more, then **they are a leech**; I treat them accordingly

Comment: @Sierra If their questions are "gimme teh codez" or similar, then yes.  If the questions are well researched, explained and give a clear example, then I'd disagree.

Comment: @TripeHound this whole page is feel good hugfest for question askers. I agree, good questions are important. However lets not kid ourselves; without answers this site isnt worth anything

Comment: "Asking good questions is contributing" -- excellent!

Comment: @Sierra without questions (good or bad) this site **won't have a single answer**... I agree about leechers but not about good askers

Answer (score 42):

### Being a great asker is as good as being a great answerer.

Asking good questions is a really great way to contribute making a bigger and better community.

A question can be bad, for sure; and as stated before make sure your questions are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [can actually be answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But, a well accepted question receives upvotes, visits AND answers because users find it interesting, not because they know or don't know the answer itself.

In other side, we can ask something than Jedi's of some technologies can find basic or elemental, but we, poor mortals, we have knowledge lacks (usually unknown) that this questions and Jedi's answers put light into.

In conclusion: **NEVER STOP ASKING GOOD QUESTIONS!**

Comment: I could not agree more with this. There have been periods on some of the smaller SE sites I frequent where most of the questions are off-topic ones by new users, and you have a bunch of high-rep people who only answer questions sitting around staring at each other, wondering what to do with themselves. Great questions are vital to an SE site.

Comment: Couldn't really follow the part about jedi, but i think i get your point.

Comment: Funny enough, if I look at my rep earned from a single post, my best question beats my best answer hands down.

Comment: @PM77-1 wow. Nothing like some real evidence to prove a point.

Answer (score 19):

**Short answer: no.** For the most part, questions are self-contained. If it's a good, well-researched question, then you'll get good, well-researched answers.

**Slighty longer answer:** I will say that I've noticed that higher-rep users tend to ask better questions. (Put another way: lower-rep users tend to ask worse questions.) And this makes sense, since high-rep users have been around longer and know what makes a good question, and if you ask good questions you'll gain reputation. I wouldn't say that makes me **less likely** to answer a low-rep user, but it does make me **more likely** to answer a high-rep user. I should note that it doesn't really matter whether that high rep came from asking or answering.

**Long answer:** In addition to asking good, well-researched questions, the other thing you can do to help your "appearance" is by **upvoting and accepting answers to your old questions.** If I see the same user asking 3 questions a day in the same tag and never upvoting or accepting any answers, I'm less likely to answer questions from that user. Similarly, if it looks like a user is using Stack Overflow as google (posting a question for every little problem they have without showing much research), then that user is less likely to get an answer.

Looking at your question history, it looks like you do a good job of upvoting and accepting answers. But it looks like none of your questions have ever been upvoted, and that's probably because you aren't including an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Including an MCVE (instead of the disconnected snippets you're providing now) is the best thing you can do to help yourself get answers (and upvotes). That matters much more than your reputation or whether you answer any questions yourself.

Comment: Do you have a **Very Long Answer** :)

Comment: @newguy Yeah let me edit that in. I expect to be done in about 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @KevinWorkman 6-8 weeks? Second time hearing that in two days. I thought it was true, except it is just a meme.

Comment: @Rexford [It is a meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta), but how do you know I'm not still writing my very long answer? See also: the Baader-Meinhof Phenomenon.

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow users are trying to create a collection of questions and answers that make it easy to find solutions to programming problems or that explain different on-topic aspects of programming.

Asking questions is one way of contributing to this. Anytime you are asking a question that has not already been asked, you are adding to this collection and therefore benefitting the community as a whole.

Answer (score 5):

Let's reason it from the other way around: should you be politely required to answer questions when all you really want to do and can do is ask (on-topic, original) questions?

**Heck no!**

SO is not about keeping score; it's about quality content. If all you can do is ask questions, then one very possible scenario is that your expertise does not go so far yet that you can answer the good questions that are not going to be closed for any reason. If you don't have the expertise, you shouldn't ever feel forced to answer - it will not lead to the quality this site dictates.

Now still assuming that limit of expertise which is absolutely not the only reason for not answering, should you then not ask questions because you can't answer anything? **Heck no again**. If that were true then this would be one very exclusive Q&A site.

Let's now make a jump to the dark side of the Stack. Say you don't answer because you simply don't want to and only want to "leech". Simply put: nobody here can know what you true intentions are** and should assume you simply don't have anything to answer. Big Brother is not watching you. The question is more: do *you* feel comfortable with it? If you feel some kind of discomfort, then perhaps try to answer a thing or two and feel better.

<sub>** Unless you say so on meta...</sub>

Comment: I admit I'm a leech. I definitely learnt more from SO than I teached others. Some days I even neither ask nor answer, I just read which is the really sneaky way of leeching.

Comment: @Trilarion Meh, that's just regular service consumption as we all do.

Comment: *"Unless you say so on meta"* That's right, because everything said on Meta is required to be 100% truth.

Comment: @CodyGray Don't really know what you're getting at here. I was sort of silently referring towards the meta effect myself. If you do things that people might not agree with, better keep it to yourself.

Comment: @Gimby Totally. SO is meant to form a knowledgebase. People _read_ knowledgebases. Without readers, there is no point in their existence. Obviously a good level of contribution is required to create things _worth_ reading, but equally, if everyone contributed all the time just for the sake of doing so, we'd end up a total mess! Or, I dunno... Documentation.