# Really simple questions that are good as a FAQ, but aside from that, are lazy

Tags: discussion, questions

I stumbled across this question:
[What is a Python egg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051192/17089665)

Now, I understand that it is 12 years old, maybe at that time it wasn't as easy to find information, but we are talking 2010, not 1999, so I still think this is a valid example. Please beware that I mean what should be done for a question like this *at the time of its publication*. This is just an example, and probably, not a very good one as it was stated in the comment section.

The answer to this question must have been available on the internet, in the form of documentation, tutorials, courses etc. etc. at that time.

It is a simple question which **is good to have** in a knowledge repo-type of web, as that type of FAQ for newbies in Python, and maybe it is a good question because, again, **maybe someone in SO can explain it in a really good way for future readers to understand it easier**. But on the other side, it just doesn't meet what I would expect from a good question in SO. It looks like a lazy approach to just ask here. Shouldn't people be asking here as a last resort method?

What is the correct approach when stumbling this kind of questions?

Comment: I'm curious, why does it matter whether the question is "lazy"?

Comment: I have seen so many times people saying a question should show some research before being asked. I assume it is a basic part of SO's code of conduct.

Comment: @S.Dre What makes you think that research was as easy 12 years ago is it is now? You do touch on this in your question, but 2010 was _massively_ different to now.

Comment: A question like this is likely to receive downvotes now days, but that doesn't mean they won't receive enough upvotes to survive if the question is one people frequently enough have to bring in traffic.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine  It is an example, what if I stumble a new question like that? And again, it was 2010, the internet was already in a somewhat mature state... [example1](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/python-eggs) [example2](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/python_eggs.html)

Comment: For a mature technology, a "lazy" question asked nowadays has most likely been asked before, so find the best duplicate and flag it.

Comment: No, it's definitely not a part of the CoC. Also, while users *should* put in effort to see if their question has been asked, this effort doesn't need to be visible in question itself, as that tends to just be noise. (Note that this particular question might be unclear, etc, but the fact that any research put in by the user is not visible in the question is irrelevant).

Comment: Put another way... beginner questions are often popular *because* they are beginner questions, not because they were poorly researched or for any other reason related to the way it was asked. If a language is currently having a high influx of new users it's more likely for such questions to gain traction, particularly when that language doesn't already have a large footprint here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, @snakecharmerb, I guess if it is the *first* time to be asked here, or the by far best question about it, it still is useful for the site.

Comment: @KevinB , that makes sense.

Comment: @cigien: I wouldn't say it's irrelevant, given that the downvote tooltip is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." That certainly suggests to me that questions are expected to show research effort, and that it's reasonable for readers to consider that relevant to their voting.

Comment: @JonSkeet For up/down voting, sure, you could use that as a metric if you want. Honestly, any up/down voting is fine, so long as it's not targeted at a user. I meant it's not relevant for close-votes, which is what some users do for questions that don't show research effort. Perhaps I should have been clearer in my comment.

Comment: I recommend to go looking for a different example. This question isn't simple or lazy, and a similar question today would not be simple nor lazy either. That's a really dark pit the asker descended into...

Comment: see also: [Is it OK to ask simple questions without showing your work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334090/839601)

Comment: They are no longer called *"eggs"*, but *"[wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format)"*... (as noted in the updated answer)

Answer (score 12):

There's really nothing to do.

This is the kind of question that is perfect for its time, and perfect for the site in its current state.  As in, we *want* to preserve a question like this.  This helps others and gets them information that they need as an answer to a specific question.  There's nothing off-topic about it, even if in your assessment you consider it "lazy".

I mean *today* if you tried to ask this kind of question you'd be met with a lot of fervor and downvotes, but I don't see a reason to give this question any more vitriol or dirty looks.

Comment: Yes, I meant for a new question we find like this one. This is obviously 12 years old and given it's 'encyclopedic' nature I wouldn't suggest to touch it neither. But if we were back then and thought it was lazy, or if nowadays we find something like this.

Comment: I'm quite reluctant to use older questions as a basis on what we should do for newer questions, @S.Dre.  I'm of the impression that not a lot of painstaking thought needs to be given to a question like this if it was asked today - mostly, if there's a dupe, find the dupe.

Comment: Maybe you are right @Makoto, and this wasn't a good example to begin with.

Answer (score 10):

The question seems to be on-topic. It is one of the questions that we are looking for.

It isn't lazy. Even in the original form, it wasn't lazy. Maybe this information is freely available in the documentation, but at the time of asking it wasn't available on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a documentation of the language; it is much more. We can provide examples and a better explanation of the topic being asked for.

A lazy question is one that the asker didn't bother checking if it has been asked before on Stack Overflow. A lazy question has often grammatical issues, typos and generally looks like it was written in a hurry. Lazy questions lack a proper title that would make the question easily searchable. If it isn't an outright duplicate, then it probably has other quality issues that qualify it for one of the available close reasons. That, however, was not the case with the question you gave as an example.

Simple questions are good if they are well-written and haven't been asked before.