# How to behave with a user repeatedly pinging me in comments

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132854/how-to-bringback-an-object-to-its-original-position-after-rotation-in-unity?noredirect=1#comment75289509_44132854) is actually ongoing. It is related to some Unity3D trivial stuff.

To make the question more clear, I added a comment to ask her what she exactly wants to achieve. She did answer once, which was fine. But she then posted the same comment again some times later, tagging me again, this time "inopportunely blocking" her caps lock touch. Was she angry or was it an accident, the mystery is still ongoing.

A user who is used to answer in the unity3d tag came to answer the question, with a really simple answer which should at least partially have solved her problem. The problem is that I am not sure if the asker is reluctant to actually put an effort to adapt her code with the given answer, if she just doesn't understand the purpose of the answer she was given, or if she does understand, but the answer really doesn't help her with her problem. We then had the opportunity to see more inappropriate caps lock when she edited her question and answered that user.

What is the best behaviour to have in this particular case? Should I just flag the question as unclear, or ask her again to be more specific on what she wants to achieve? Should I flag this specific caps lock comment? Or should I take more time in the comments to explain to her how to use and behave on Stack Overflow?

I would personally have gone for the last option, but I don't know if the comments is the best place to do so, and I don't think the user would take the time to follow me in a chat for this purpose.

Comment: Might be what we call a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).

Comment: If you would like to explain to the user that excessive commenting (or all-caps) is counterproductive, and you are willing to spend the time doing so, please go ahead. Users should be grateful for that help, and if they react in an even worse fashion, just flag their comments as rude/non-constructive etc.

Comment: On an answer, if you get too many follow-up comments, you may find that an OP is taking advantage of your help and is looking to get infinite follow-ups. Related help is fine, if you have time, but where their request diverges from the original question, ask them to ask a new question.

Comment: This question had a whole of red flags. If i remember right, the first comment was targeting some (not related) User, bagging for help. Sorry that this turn out like this.

Comment: @Smartis User was pinging a specific user who previously answered one of her question to ask him to answer this one too yes.

Comment: Since the question was asked, most of the content discussed in this question has been cleaned. I reported the pinging comment which was deleted with all the other comments apparently. All the caps lock in the question has been edited by some users, and the user ended up giving more information, leading to an accepted answer. The user apparently edited the question again some days later, apparently because it didn't totally solve her problem in the end.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Deal with each issue independently.

For the comment, that certainly seems abusive to me.  Someone posting the same comment they'd posted earlier, but some time later and with caps lock on is clearly not an accident, and I can't see any reason to do it other than to annoy the person you're replying to, trying to get their attention after they've specifically chosen to not respond.  I would use a custom flag for this and explain why you feel the comment isn't appropriate, and I'd expect a mod to delete it.

As far as you being unsure if the answer solves the question author's problem, that one you can just not worry about (unless you know that it won't for some reason, in which case, feel free to provide that feedback).  If the question author responds with any problems they have with the answer, you're more than welcome to use that feedback to either help them understand the answer, improve on the answer, post your own answer that accounts for those problems, or whatever.  If the OP doesn't respond with any problems they have with the answer, and you honestly don't know if the answer will be able to help them, then just don't worry about it; pestering the OP to ask them if the answer works for them isn't helpful.

As far as the caps lock text edited into the question, I don't see anything abusive or inappropriate about it.  I'd certainly edit the question to remove the caps, bold, and improper code formatting, because it's just improper formatting that detracts from the post, but I don't see any reason to flag here.

If you think that the question doesn't contain enough information to be answered, then sure, by all means, vote to close the question as unclear.  If you would like to, you're also more than welcome to comment to explain to the author what is unclear, or how they might be able to improve the question, if you have any ideas.  If you don't feel you have anything to add beyond the close reason, then feel free to just let it speak for itself and not comment.

Comment: Clear enough for me. I will do as you said and treat each one of those problems independantly.