# Too Broad Question and "Still Not Working"-Comments

Tags: discussion

I flagged the question below as 'Too broad', but I did (different) tries to help.

[Error in uploading file php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566043/error-in-uploading-file-php/44566162?noredirect=1)

I suppose the question is too broad to solve all underlying problems. After different tries (via updated answer, comments), I get every time again "Updated my code, but doesn't work."-comments. What should I do in this case?

Comment: See also [What is a help vampire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)

Comment: If you don't want to stay and help a help vampire - just walk away. There is no shame in that.

Comment: In cases like this I often ask the OP to ask a new question with an updated MCVE if the changes still do not work.

Comment: Yeah. How do you politely inform that updating code is not enough, you also have to keep thinking about it :/

Comment: Thanks for the votes to close. My goal has been achieved :-)