# Am I doing something wrong or is the user a help vampire?

Tags: discussion, help-vampire

For some days now I have a back and forth on the comments with the questioner of this post: *[MakeValid not working for a single model object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708889/makevalid-not-working-for-a-single-model-object/45717050)* which is a continuation (under my suggestion) of this post's *[Equivalent of PostGIS ST_MakeValid in Django GEOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos)* back and forth.

I do believe that I made my answer clear enough in both cases but I see that the questioner still asks for the same things over and over.

Have I done something wrong with my answers? 
Am I not clear enough and need to change something (and what)? 
Do I need to be more patient and it is my problem? 
Is he a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) and should I leave him alone?

---

**08/23/2017:** After the user received knowledge for this post from [Christian Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6640099/christian-dean), he accepted both answers.

Comment: I can smell blood in the water...

Comment: Is it mine @MartinJames should I worry? Should I get a band-aid??

Comment: Only if the vamp has drunk too much.

Comment: If you feel that there *might be* a help-vampire nearby... well...12 out of 10 times... there *is* a help-vampire nearby.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Comment: and... we gave the suspected help vampire a gold badge...

Comment: @Jeutnarg It should have been silver!! They don't like silver!!

Comment: I actually used to have a custom Chrome script to hide comments from two specific users so I wasn't baited.   Highly recommended.

Comment: @JohnMoutafis that's werewolves.  The vamps are unaffected by silver.  Recipie for vamps is wooden stake through heart, fire or beheading.

Comment: @MartinJames depends on the folklore: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vampire_traits_in_folklore_and_fiction (see on weaknesses)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis OK, I'll check with the were pack in the club on Friday night.  I would ask the vamp couple who run the bar, but they're on vacation ATM.

Comment: @MartinJames But it is a "dead" season now (subzero pun and I know it :P )

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## Stop answering this person.

Just walk away.  You've provided *more* than enough information for their question.

The worst part is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631855/equivalent-of-postgis-st-makevalid-in-django-geos#comment78389870_45633779) that they left:

> Please see if you can help me here as well. [link redacted]

## You need to stop engaging with this person.

You've done everything right in answering their question as posed.  The rest is more up to them than anything else.

Comment: Introduce them to Mr. Pointy.

Comment: @MartinJames:  He's a sharp fella, I feel like his impact is felt once he comes in the room, y'know.

Comment: @Makoto not much fun to hang around with though - he's far too wooden.

Comment: @JonClements Nobody's mentioning it specifically, but we all have a stake in solving this problem...

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for your (moral) help! :)

Comment: Please flag comments like that. Of all the pointless comments that get flagged, these are some of the most worthy. Spamming links to your question all over the place is not okay.

Comment: @MartinJames Mr. Pointy?

Comment: @AndyJ http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Pointy

Comment: @MartinJames, next time you introduce something new like `Mr. Pointy` ... do provide a reference as well instead of confusing others.

Comment: Had a similar exchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159118/using-the-projection-camera-technique-in-c-sharp/45213179#45213179). After several follow-up questions (which are now deleted so it looks like I'm talking to myself) I repeatedly mentioned that figuring out the details is part of the learning-process.

Comment: @Rahul: That would defeat the purpose of a pop culture reference, which is to delight those who happen to get it.

Comment: "next time you make an inside joke, provide a reference with it"... You'd think that people here (of all places) would appreciate the value of Googling something yourself lol

Answer (score -37):

This is not directed at OP, but SO users in general.

**You are here for one of two reasons; to get help or to give help.**

It numbs my mind, the culture here of vilifying the people trying to get help.

**"Help Vampire"?** Is there an acceptable amount of help someone should ask for?  Are they monsters for not understanding something as quickly or easily as you?

Sometimes I wish SO would do away with points and badges in hopes to quell the elitist philosophy that has grown so strong here.

As someone here to *give help*, is it your responsibility to help improve the overall quality of the site? Yes, of course.  But your **primary** responsibility is to HELP INDIVIDUALS.  You don't know what language they speak natively, what their experience or background is.

bleh.

Comment: "Help vampire" is a colloquialism that has [a very specific meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire). It doesn't just mean someone seeking help.

Comment: Surely you would agree that there is a difference between giving help and giving unpaid contract work.  We're not trying to be mean here.  We're only explaining that a user does not have the privilege to come here and ask us to essentially do their job for them.  You would be well served reading the question, what the OP was truly asking of the asker here, and what a help vampire really is.  They're more common than you realize, and the only thing we can kill them with is lots and lots of fire.  Or Mr. Pointy.

Comment: Sure, there is abuse from some seekers, but on a daily basis I see way more abuse from "helpers".  This probably wasn't the place, but there really is no place and it frustrates me to no end.

Comment: Maybe you should strike up your own Meta SO discussion on this matter.  You may find yourself *very* enlightened afterwards.

Comment: I doubt it, I already know I'm in the nonvocal minority.

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that your remarks would be (only barely) better in a separate SO topic than here as this isn't answering the premise.  It's more of a venting session.  If you had an actual talking point to ask about, then that'd be fantastic.

Comment: What kind of "abuse"? are you flagging said "abuse"?

Comment: consider giving a read to [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601) _"You have it backwards, I think..."_

Comment: That's an interesting read, thanks.

Comment: No, neither of those two reasons is why I am here.

Comment: You are aware that being obligated to do work for no wages is called 'slavery', and that this is illegal in many jurisdictions?

Comment: 'You don't know what...their experience or background is' sure, we do - they are professional and/or enthusiast programmers.  It is generaly accepted that this excludes beginners whose knowledge is insufficient to comprehend answers without continual hand-holding.