# Moving a discussion outside the Stack Overflow platform

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Is it advised to move a discussion outside Stack Overflow? An OP who I tried to help has too little reputation to join a chat room. And he is asking me to email him for further discussions.

What should I do?

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190832/how-to-change-style-buttom/49191669?noredirect=1#49190832).

Comment: Depends on _do you want to help the poster_ that much...

Comment: If you need a chat or other communication for solving a question, then it's most probably a bad fit for SO.

Comment: Ignore and move on. This person is in a mode to outsource problems, to you.

Comment: No one can really say what you should do outside of SO.. But [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) is relevant to your scenario

Comment: So you answer a post the answer is clear but Op wan't you to do the copy past ? What's the next step ?  Will you host  and maintain the application ?

Comment: I just spoke to the OP over skype. The fundamental problem was with the language as he is not fluent in English(but Russian) and was unable to comprehend what we really meant on our answers. But, when I did a screen-share and explained the steps to inspect and solve, he was surprisingly capable of picking it up so quick. I believe we all(including myself) should show a bit more compassion, willingness to help, with less prejudice while trying to help others as there could be barriers of language, experience, disability etc and consider our time worth spending such extra efforts. Thank you all.

Comment: That's fair. But that's not what Stack Overflow is for. So you were completely on your own here, I'm glad it turned out okay.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not advised. Stack Overflow is meant to take a question and produce a long-lived page that resolves that question and is easy to find. Then the next person who has the question doesn't even need to post!

You're of course free to communicate with whomever you like, wherever you like. But if a question is not resolvable without going to another channel for a discussion, then the question is not acceptable for Stack Overflow. A question here must contain *all* required information.

So you should expect the question to be closed and eventually deleted if you take it off-site to resolve. Otherwise it's leaving [an enormously frustrating dead end](https://xkcd.com/979/) for future readers.

All that said, it's possible to salvage the situation. Go ahead off-site, have your discussion, work everything out. Then, armed with that new set of information, *come back*. Edit the question so that it's actually complete.* And provide the answer.

Now we have an OP who got an answer, a document for the future, and you get recognition for a solution. Win-win-win.

---

*You could also [post a brand new one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463) if editing is not going to work, for any reason.