# Should I flag comments that add requirements to the question as "No longer needed"?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903877/unable-to-save-a-float-value-to-a-bitfield-structure) today that was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18903944) well.

The original poster of the question commented something along the lines of
"Thank you. I forgot to include xxx in my question, could you please help with it, too?"

The comment has now been deleted, but I wonder if that was because it included "Thank you."

Should I flag these types of comments as "No longer needed"?

Comment: It sounds like the OP was trying to sneak in another question via the comments. I can't find a reference for this, but once answered, the scope of a question shouldn't change as it can invalidate existing answers. Broadening the scope of the question in the comments is also frowned upon because comments are second-class citizens which can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I think you're looking for [Exit strategies for chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/168333).

Comment: Also see [Help Vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**There isn't a universal rule here; you have to decide on a case-by-case basis whether the comment is actually needed or not.** That's why there are flaggers who make the initial decision and also moderators who review that decision.

In this case, you flagged the following comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18903944):

> Thanks a lot for help. Actually i was missing something. The value was supposed to be taken as float from user and a corresponding scaling factor was supposed to be given. For 0.8 it was 0.1. 0.8/0.1 passed in integer value which was stored in the bitfield.

In response to your flag, a moderator deleted the comment.

I have to say, I wouldn't have deleted it. I've undeleted it now. I don't see how the comment qualifies for "no longer needed". There was no edit to the answer that obsoleted it, and furthermore, there was a *response* to the comment that has now become incoherent with the deletion of the original comment.

If that original comment is going to be deleted, then the reply needs to be deleted as well. This one:

> Your original code had only 4 bits for `var5`, so that means you can encode 0.0 to 1.5 in steps of 0.1, but you can't encode 3.4 (see your original post).

But, again, I wouldn't delete that one because it does seem to actually convey information. I'm sure plenty of folks will disagree with me about this, but I prefer *not* to delete comments that convey useful information, unless they are either unfriendly/rude or have become demonstrably obsolete.

So, since I was keeping the reply, I would have also needed to keep the original. At least, that's the snap decision that I would have made from the flag dashboard. Going through and reading the question, answer, and all the comments thoroughly, I can understand why one would say that both comments are "no longer needed" and can be deleted. Who in 2019 really cares what the asker was trying to do in 2013? The larger Q&A can stand the test of time, but the motivations and/or errors in the original code aren't really important anymore.

**If you weren't sure that your flag was correct, why did you flag the comment?**

---

Speaking of "no longer needed" comments, there *is* one there that was *clearly* no longer needed:

> This notation is new to me, but I have now seen it twice in the last week.  ( **(u64*)&x; // reinterpret the double* ) .  Nice.

This fails the "conveys useful information" test. Who really cares that the notation is new to user X, or that they've seen it twice in the last week? The only information it conveys is that someone likes/endorses the notation, which can be vaguely useful, except such sentiment is better conveyed through upvotes.

I've gone ahead and deleted that comment now.

Comment: I was asking this for future reference. I was actually debating whether or not to include the question/answer pair.